# unit testing angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I would like to start doing unit testing for my angularjs project. That's far from being straight forward, I find it really difficult. I'm using Karma and Jasmine. For testing my routes and the app dependencies, I'm fine. But how would you test a directive like this one ?

```
angular.module('person.directives', []).
directive("person", function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "person/views/person.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        myPerson: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    }        
}
```

});

How would I test for instance that the template was found ?

Comment: There's a video on testing directives, might help - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB5b67Cg6bc

Answer (score 15):

Here is the way to go https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing

Basically, you use `beforeEach` to *create*, *compile* and *expose* an element and it's scope, then you simulate scope changes and event handlers and see if the code reacts and update elements and scope appropriately. Here is a pretty simple example.

Assume this:

```js
scope: {
  myPerson: '='
},
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
  element.bind('click', function() {console.log('testes');
    scope.$apply('myPerson = "clicked"');
  });
}
```

We expect that when user clicks the element with the directive, `myPerson` property becomes `clicked`. This is the behavior we need to test. So we expose the compiled directive (bound to an element) to all specs:

```js
var elm, $scope;

beforeEach(module('myModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  elm = angular.element('<div t my-person="outsideModel"></div>');
  $compile(elm)($scope);
}));
```

Then you just assert that:

```js
it('should say hallo to the World', function() {
  expect($scope.outsideModel).toBeUndefined(); // scope starts undefined
  elm.click(); // but on click
  expect($scope.outsideModel).toBe('clicked'); // it become clicked
});
```

Plnker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jKbrCp). You need jQuery to this test, to simulate `click()`.

Comment: as for template html, for dynamically loading into $templateCache. you could just use html2js karma pre-processor

this boils down to adding templates '*.html' to your files in the conf.js file
as well 
preprocessors = {
  '*.html': 'html2js'
};

    and specify the htmls as modules in your js testing file